# i have a webservice which calls one url and return some data in xml format

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I had made this webservice which is accessing another url which return some data now the problem is when i try to access this service from other network then my work place it fails so how can i access it and as i check it goes to my server url not the url assigned to that server

the code is given below

```
[WebMethod]
    public XmlElement GetDemo(string demo)
    {
        //XmlNode urlText;
        string urlText;
        string url = string.Format("https://demo.net/wsvh/bas/veBasic?demos={0}", demo);
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                urlText = reader.ReadToEnd();

            }
        }


        // Return the DataSet as an XmlElement.
        XmlDataDocument xmldata = new XmlDataDocument();
      //  xmldata.LoadXml(string.Format("<vehicleBasic>{0}</vehicleBasic>", urlText));
        XmlElement xmlElement = xmldata.DocumentElement;
        return xmlElement;
    }
```

the output its giving is

as so on like.

Comment: I think that depends on the browser or the tool you use to read the xml.

Comment: Please attempt to clarify your question a bit more, your title and question are lacking a bit.  It reads like "I have a blue car" which means nothing like a question.\

Comment: i had tried all the browsers getting same result i just need the url result as it is in my webservice